# Is it correct to say "gummy candies are flexible/stretchy etc"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

We say:

-"**The shirt is elastic**"

-"**The plastic tube is flexible**"

> [Gummies, gummi candies, gummy candies, or jelly sweets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gummy_candy) are a broad
> category of gelatin-based chewable sweets.

[image]

We say:

-"**The shirt is elastic**"

-"**The plastic tube is flexible**"

In an analogy expression, what is the common adjective that we use to talk about "**Gummy candy**" in everyday English?

For example, "**Gummy candies are...**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of those words are correct to describe gummies. But since it is food we most commonly say they are **chewy**.

"Gummy candies are chewy."

Stretchy, elastic, squishy, and flexible all describe the candy correctly, but would only be used to emphasize their physical properties (such as in a chemistry class). "Chewy" is the only option that hints toward their edibleness and thus it is the most used.